# How to use IOArray in Haskell records?

Tags: arrays, haskell, record

I'm trying to adapt the example code from haskell.org but cant seem to get it to work.

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Arrays#Mutable_IO_arrays_.28module_Data.Array.IO.29

```
import Data.Array.IO                                                                                          

data SomeData = SomeData {                                                                                    
  array :: IO (IOArray Int Float)                                                                             
}                                                                                                             

main = do                                                                                                     
  let d = SomeData { array <- newArray (1,255) 1.0 :: IO (IOArray Int Float) } 
  a <- readArray (d array) 1                                                                                  
  writeArray (d array) 1 64                                                                                   
  b <- readArray (d array) 1                                                                                  
  print (a,b)
```

Comment: Please expand more on "I cant seem to get it to work". What doesn't work? Do you get a compile error (if yes, please include the error message in your post)?

Comment: I'm not sure if compiler errors help since depend on what I try I get different ones. The code above does not compile, but it should be obvious what I want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot mix record creation syntax and monadic bind, so the line

```
let d = SomeData { array <- newArray (1,255) 1.0 :: IO (IOArray Int Float) }
```

is invalid syntax. You need to do the bind on a separate line. Also, your field accessors are the wrong way around, you access the field with `array d` not `d array` and you need to remove the `IO` wrapper from your field declaration.

```
data SomeData = SomeData { array :: IOArray Int Float) }

main = do
  arr <- newArray (1,255) 1.0
  let d = SomeData { array = arr }
  a <- readArray (array d) 1
  writeArray (array d) 1 64
  b <- readArray (array d) 1
  print (a,b)
```